# SUMIFS for Text values in the Sum Range

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use a function similar to SUMIF but the values are text. Here is the
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNiVO.png).

I want the result to be like the image below.

[Result Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZE0x.png)

I've tried using QUERY group-by but it sorts the concatenated text. I want the concatenated text to appear in the original order from the data. The closest formula I've tried is using a SUMIF since the criterion is checked one-by-one against the criterion range but it is only for numbers.

```
={unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),arrayformula(SUMIF(A2:A,unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),B2:B))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a similar criteria but with FILTER and TEXTJOIN I think you'll be able to get to your desired result:

```
    ={UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),
BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),LAMBDA(uniq,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=uniq))))}
```

Comment: I did not know that a function LAMBDA existed. This is amazing thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:A),{u,MAP(u,LAMBDA(μ,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=μ))))})
```

Comment: This is also correct and  a more elegant solution. Also didn't know about the LET function. Using this even simpler than QUERY. Thanks!